# Получить в PHP массив со всеми значениями из MySQL базы соответствующие условию

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос к mysql базе данных:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `date` IN ('2021-09-01', '2021-09-02', '2021-09-03', '2021-09-04')
```

2021-09-01 и 2021-09-04 значения есть в базе данных

2021-09-02 и 2021-09-03 нет значений в базе данных

Нужно получить в PHP массив вида:

```
array (4) (
   [0]=>'id',                                                 //2021-09-01
   [1]=>(какое-либо значение обозначающее, что данных нет),   //2021-09-02
   [3]=>(какое-либо значение обозначающее, что данных нет),   //2021-09-03
   [4]=>'id',                                                 //2021-09-04
)
```

Comment: чем не устраивает вариант получить в значения null и при выводе информации в шаблон в цикле выводить данные, если null - то какое-то значение обозначающее что данных нет?

Comment: Что конкретно подразумевается под фразой «нет значений»? Строки с NULL или полное отсутствие таких строк?

Comment: @andreymal автор вопроса хочет получить ответ без пропусков дней. Но скорее всего ему проще реализовать такой подход на стороне php, чем делать сложный запрос

Comment: @ArchDemon там вряд ли сложный запрос будет. скорей COELESCE применить и усё. Но как по мне, если ты пыхер - то и делать там надо)) ну и контроля больше. Например если захочется надпись поменять

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, но как это сделать, я не знаю?

Comment: @andreymal любое значение, которое можно определить в PHP скрипте, как ответ на запрос данных с датой 2021-09-02 и 2021-09-03

Comment: @ArchDemon верно ответ должен состоять из 4х записей, а не из 2х. На стороне PHP можно это реализовать. Думаю есть способ сделать это сразу в запросе к базе.

Comment: @user463459 что конкретно не знаете? не умете к БД подключаться из пыхи? не умеете работать в пыхе с sql? не умете в пыхе получать данные из бд? или выводить? или что?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пробую делать запрос по всякому, в том числе и с COELESCE, но боюсь провожусь ещё неделю такими темпами, пока как следует запросы не выучу. В запросах к БД не силён.

Comment: Ну если не сильны, то можно решить на стороне php. Будет быстрее

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT `date`, mytable.`date` IS NOT NULL presence
FROM (SELECT '2021-09-01' `date` UNION ALL
      SELECT '2021-09-02' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2021-09-03' UNION ALL
      SELECT '2021-09-04') dates
LEFT JOIN `mytable` USING (`date`)
```

Comment: хз, сортировка значений другая)) возможно топикстартеру достаточно добавить `ORDER BY \`date\``

Comment: @Jean-Claude Так автор вообще не озаботился деталями... ни как сортировать, ни структурой/данными таблицы, из коей надо получить показанный результат... вообще практически ничего не сказано по существу. На таких скудных исходных данных на большее может не рассчитывать.

Comment: ну а как же, ты обязан выпытывать))